# Does ios app with Crashlytics uses Advertisement Identifier (IDFA)?

Tags: ios, crashlytics, idfa

I'm currently uploading my App to the App Store and Apple is asking me if this app uses IDFA. I'm using the Crashlytics for tracking bugs and I don't know if it uses IDFA or not, and if it does which checkboxes should I hit?

[image]

I referred  https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/advanced-setup.html?highlight=idfa, but I am not understanding "The IDFA will only be collected if your app links against AdSupport.framework."

To check on each third party SDK if they use or not the IDFA i used this command:

```
grep -r advertisingIdentifier .
```

I got this,

```
Binary file ./Pods/Crashlytics/iOS/Crashlytics.framework/Crashlytics matches
./Pods/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/Internal/AppEvents/FBSDKAppEventsUtility.m:result = [[manager advertisingIdentifier] UUIDString];
```

Please tell to does my app uses IDFA? YES/NO, if YES then for what?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Crashlytics does not use Advertisement Identifier (IDFA) or does not link  an AdSupport framework by default.

Crashlytics explicitly ask you to add AdSupport framework only when using advanced features like audience insights. https://docs.fabric.io/apple/answers/audience-insights.html

So, your app does not use IDFA. The answer is NO